# How do I determine which methods are used by a Java class

Tags: java, class, import

I need to provide a report of which APIs are used by our code, and exactly which methods are called. For a Windows DLL, I would use "dumpbin /imports" - is there an equivalent for a Java .class file?

javap seems to be the obvious place to look, but I can't find any options that seem to do what I'm after.

Comment: What exactly are you looking for:
 - what 3rd party packages/classes/methods are used by your code?
 - what methods are *not* used to look for deadcode?

Also, keep in mind that such analysis may not be exhaustive if you use reflection.

Note that in the simplest case, you may simply be looking to grep for all import statements in *.java files...

Comment: What 3rd party packages/classes/methods are used by our code.

Specifically, we're delivering a .jar to a customer, and they want to know exactly which methods it calls. Just grepping for import statements would tell us which packages we make use of, but they want a list of every single method (and before you ask, no, I don't know why).

Comment: Just in case you would try to convince the customer otherwise: so what if some library invokes some method form another library...? Or what if your own method (that calls some library method) is never invoked?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`javap -c class1 class2 ... | grep invoke`

You will get all the runtime calls. You should filter them from your APIs and you will get calls to imported methods.

You might also want to determine used imported fields:

`javap -c class1 class2 ... | grep getstatic` (search also putstatic, putfield, getfield)

Comment: Thanks! I knew that there had to be *some* way :-)

Answer (score 1):

It's brutal, but you could try something like this:

1. do a global search/replace in your code for "import
   x.y.Z" with static class Z{}  where
   package x.y is from your thirdparty
2. jar run your compile script (or copy the errors from your IDE if possible)
3. process the compilation errors looking for
   "`The method xxx is undefined`" type
   of messages

Comment: The method I described could return erroneous results if a variable is named the same as a method, but the method described here wouldn't have that disadvantage. I don't think this would be so brutal if you write a perl/python/ruby/sed script to do this. +1 for a correct and workable solution.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions guys. I was hoping that it might be simpler than this - similar to dumpbin /exports on Windows or nm -u on Linux. Ah well, sigh, such is life.

Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

How about Apache/Maven [jxr](http://maven.apache.org/jxr/)?

Comment: I've not used jxr before, but from what I can see from the documentation it generates HTML from our source, and won't tell us anything about 3rd party methods called by it (see comment above)?

Comment: It as an API. You can call it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know a specific tool to do this, but it seems to me it could be done with moderate difficulty using a perl script, if you have the jar or source.

You can run the jar through jad http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JAD_(JAva_Decompiler) to generate the source, then write a perl script that:

1. Scans through each file of your source

   a. finds all import reg expression strings

   b finds all source files in the decompiled third party source that matches the imported
      package

   c. for each file in the third party, extract the method names

   d. if it matches, save the method + class + package.

This can of course be made much more efficient - you could make an hash table of all packages, and within that, a hash table of all methods for the third party.

Once a method is used, you can delete it from the table since you don't need to look for it again.

But probably the brute force method is sufficient, because this is not a computationally intensive problem (though of course for a human it would be very labor intensive!).

Substitute ruby/python/php/sed/awk for perl if that is your preference.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a lot of power and flexibility, I would definitely take a look at the [ASM library](http://asm.ow2.org/)

There are basically a lot of great tools for analysing and manipulating java bytecode. One of the ones you may find most useful is a vistor-based API which can walk through the internals of any class and perform any analysis you want (in your case detecting which other classes / packages are referenced).